# Расположение поля toast

Tags: android-toast

У меня есть метод, который показывает сообщение об ошибке. Сейчас поле вылезает в самом верху по середине, а как сделать, чтобы оно вылезало немного ниже самого верха и  так же посередине?

```
public void oshibka () {
    Toast problem = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ss, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    problem.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
    problem.show();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пишете `Gravity.TOP`, поэтому и в самом верху.
Напишите `Gravity.CENTER` (будет в середние экрана) и подберите вручную оффсет, который вам нужен.

Например, так:

```
problem.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 20);
```

Возможные значения параметра Gravity: [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html).

***Неудобства метода setGravity:*** в качестве оффсета он принимает целые числа, которые обозначают число пикселей. Поэтому вертикальный оффсет `200` на экране 480x800 будет четверть экрана, а на экране 2160х3840 эти 200 пикселей и не заметишь. Можно использовать метод [setMargin()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setMargin(float,%20float)). Он задает относительное смещение тоста. Эти параметры выведут тостер ниже середины экрана:

```
problem.setMargin(0, (float) 0.33);
```